# Adding/subtracting miliseconds days to miliseconds date

Tags: java, date

I am converting days to miliseconds By :-

> days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

When I am Subtracting/Adding one day gives proper output like-

```
Date d= new Date(); // Sat May 25 10:16:38 IST 2019

Date d1 = new Date(d.getTime() + 1 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); //Sun May 26 10:16:38 IST 2019

Date d1 = new Date(d.getTime() - 1 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); //Sun May 25 10:16:38 IST 2019
```

But add/subtracting gives inappropriate output When I am trying to add/subtract today days (Ex. Today is 25th May)

```
Date d= new Date();

Date newDate = new Date(d.getTime() + 25 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); //Tue Apr 30 17:36:35 IST 2019

newDate = new Date(d.getTime() - 25 * 24 * 3600 * 1000);  //Wed Jun 19 03:42:10 IST 2019
```

I dont know why I am getting this output. Please help me.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated, and also completely unsuited for the date math you are doing. Instead use `LocalDate` or another class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Your problem is `int` overflow.

Answer (score 1):

25 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 equals to 2160000000  in int format(all parameter in multiple is int) and overfelow this operation.

You should type cast to long format and pass this to new Date constructor.

for example 25 day later:

```
Date d= new Date();
Date newDate = new Date(d.getTime() + 25L * 24 * 3600 * 1000); //Tue Apr 30 17:36:35 IST 2019
```

but better solution for 25 day after yor time is:

```
Date d = new Date();

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime( d );
c.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR , +25 );

Date newDate = c.getTime();
```